# Extract data from html with random class names

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-scraping, jss

I have a web page that looks like this. The class names seem to be randomly generated on every page load.

Either of the following two XPath expressions can extract "Item 1" from the document. However these expressions are fragile and will break as soon as the page format changes.

- `/div/div/div/div/div/div/h3/span`
- `//div/h3/span`

Is there a general solution to extract data from such a page?

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="styles__Header-sc-120s71t-1 bVobsP">
    <h6 class="jss85xpic jsspbfkgl jssfrl2gs" style="max-width: 100%;">Title</h6>
    <div class="styles__Description-sc-120s71t-2 cilEqp">
        <p class="jss85xpic jsspbfkgl jssou361l" style="max-width: 100%;">Description</p>
    </div>
    <div class="styles__ItemsList-sc-120s71t-3 gyRIpM">
        <div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" role="button" tabindex="0" class="styles__Wrapper-sc-1xl58bi-2 gKTcIQ" style="max-width: 100%;">
            <div class="styles__FlexContainer-sc-1xl58bi-4 bLvOGI">
                <div class="styles__TextWrapper-sc-1xl58bi-9 liomPZ">
                    <div class="styles__Title-sc-1xl58bi-5 eqysaj">
                        <h3 class="jss85xpic jsspbfkgl jssws5ijf" style="max-width: 100%;"><span itemprop="name">Item 1</span></h3>
                    </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The page is well-defined, albeit with random class names. Is there a general solution to the problem of random class names?

Comment: apparently "Item 1" is inside a span that you can get with `//span[@itemprop="name"]`, is it not?

Comment: Is the target `span` always inside an `<h3>` tag?

Comment: You say the page is well-defined, but you also ask, what can I do if the format changes. So the short answer is no, there's no good solution. You have to have something that is always true, so you can find it. You have a `p` inside a `div`, and a `span` inside an `h3`. If those are always true, then you have something to work with. You can do quite a bit though these days finding elements with specific properties; something to check out. See ebessa's comment above.

Comment: @ebessa @Jack Fleeting Yes that is correct. `//span[@itemprop="name"]` would work and `span` is usually inside `h3`. That answers my question as stated. Thank you. I have a follow-up question which should be its own topic.

Comment: @wazz The page is well-defined in the sense that while the html format may change, the rendered page always looks consistent. You are correct, this problem can be solved by querying with specific properties. That answers my question. Thank you.